# Is it possible to use the result of a PHP function directly as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Function func() returns an array

```
<?php echo func($arg)[0] ?>
```

So this code must work, but it isn't.

Why? And how I can do it **without** assigning the result of the function to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need PHP 5.4 to do that.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

The alternative pre 5.4 is:

```
<?php $temp = func($arg); echo $temp[0] ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's so strange that this oblivious and useful feature was implemented only in 5.4

Comment: @Zhigalin There are many things strange with PHP's design and implementation .. (the very existence of variables-as-objects not withstanding).